# Churches (that are) being built

Tags: grammar

Are both the sentences correct?

1. There are churches **being built** in India.
2. There are churches **that are being built** in India.

Comment: Your  1. is called a reduced relative clause. There are lots of posts about this on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct.

(This site requires at least 30 characters in an answer.)

Comment: They  _could_ both be correct. I would understand (1) as a simple statement (people are building churches in India right now), but I would interpret _that are being built_ as a relative clause _There are churches that are being  built in India that have very high towers_.

Comment: @KateBunting In what way might (2) be incorrect to say by itself? (It seems to me that at most one might feel that the "that" is unnecessary, or not the best wording. But it seems correct to me, and might in some cases be preferred for the intention of expressing focus or emphasis.) e.g. _"Filbert admitted there were churches in India, but said he didn't think anyone was building any new ones there today. The bishop replied, "You're incorrect. There are churches that are being built in India."_

Comment: I didn't mean that it was necessarily incorrect, just that the _that are_  seems unnecessary to me and suggests a relative clause.